# Loading AlbumArtworks without OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, android, bitmap, out-of-memory

I want to load the Album-Artworks into my music app and preview them in a recyclerview. I've tried  [Googles Developer Guide](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html), but I'm actually loading about 200 Bitmaps, so this doesn't work!

I don't have an idea about how to do that!

Here's my current code:

```
if (cSong != null && cSong.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        int iIDCol = cSong.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
        int iTitleCol = cSong.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
        int iArtistCol = cSong.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
        int iAlbumCol = cSong.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM);
        int iDurationCol = cSong.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION);
        int iAlbumIDCol = cSong.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID);

        Bitmap bCover = null;
        BitmapFactory.Options bOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

        //Throws OutOfMemoryError
        /*try {
            Uri ArtworkUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
            Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ArtworkUri, iAlbumIDCol);
            ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = mContext.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");

            if (pfd != null) {
                FileDescriptor fd = pfd.getFileDescriptor();
                BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fd, null, bOptions);

                bOptions.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(bOptions, 100, 100);

                bOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

                bCover = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fd, null, bOptions);

                pfd = null;
                fd = null;
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.standardartwork, bOptions);

            bOptions.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(bOptions, 100, 100);

            bOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

            bCover = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.standardartwork, bOptions);
        }*/

        SongList.add(new Song(cSong.getLong(iIDCol), cSong.getString(iTitleCol), cSong.getString(iArtistCol), cSong.getString(iAlbumCol), cSong.getInt(iDurationCol), bCover));
    }
    while (cSong.moveToNext());
```

Any my InSampleSize Method:

```
private int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;

    int size = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight && width > reqWidth) {
        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        while ((halfHeight / size) > reqHeight && (halfWidth / size) > reqWidth) {
            size *= 2;
        }
    }

    return size;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using the Library Picasso, which handles the Loading-Process of the Image.

```
Picasso.with(mContext).load(ImageUri).resize(Width, Height).into(ImageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Holding 200 bitmaps in memory is not a good idea even though they are downscaled. The easiest solution would be saving the Uri to the cover instead of Bitmap and decode a Bitmap only when you need it.

So the parsing code would look like this:

```
Uri artworkUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
if (cSong != null && cSong.moveToFirst()) {
do {
    int iIDCol = cSong.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
    int iTitleCol = cSong.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
    int iArtistCol = cSong.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
    int iAlbumCol = cSong.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM);
    int iDurationCol = cSong.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION);
    int iAlbumIDCol = cSong.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID);
    Uri coverUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(artworkUri, iAlbumIDCol);

    SongList.add(new Song(cSong.getLong(iIDCol), cSong.getString(iTitleCol), cSong.getString(iArtistCol), cSong.getString(iAlbumCol), cSong.getInt(iDurationCol), coverUri));
}
while (cSong.moveToNext());
```

And in your `RecyclerView.Adapter` `onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)` method do the decoding:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Bitmap image = decodeBitmap(songsList.get(position).getBitmapUrl());
    if (image != null) {
        holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(image);
    } else {
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.standardartwork);
    }
}

private Bitmap decodeBitmap(Uri uri) {
    ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = mContext.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
    try {
        if (pfd != null) {
            FileDescriptor fd = pfd.getFileDescriptor();
            BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fd, null, bOptions);

            bOptions.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(bOptions, 100, 100);

            bOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

            return BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fd, null, bOptions);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This will allow you to keep in memory only the bitmaps that you actually have to show on the screen, others will be recycled.

NOTE: The snippets are here just for an illustration how your problem could be solved, but this can reduce performance of your RecyclerView, because decoding is done on the main thread. You won't notice it if your images are rather small, but you'll have to do decoding asynchronously if they are large. In case of large images, consider using libraries for image processing like Picasso or Glide.